# How to convert JavaFx project to Gradle project?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, javafx

I'm building a JavaFx project using Eclipse and I have a file structure like this:

`Project
│   .classpath
│   .gitignore
│   .project
│   build.fxbuild
│   README.md
│   (sqlite).db (*local database this project operates on)
│
├───.settings
│       ...
│
├───bin
│       ...
│
├───lib
│       ...
│
└───src
    ├───application
    |       ...
    │       Main.java
    │
    ├───controllers
    │       ...
    │
    ├───css
    │       ...
    │
    ├───fxml
    │       ...
    │
    └───resources
            123.jpg`

**How do I convert this into a gradle project?** I'm totally new to gradle and I have hard time finding documentation to get started.

*I'm using JavaFx 8 and jdk-9.

Answer (score 2):

> I have hard time finding documentation to get started.

Gradle is well-documented, if you google you find a lot of beginner's tutorials as well, and there's lots of examples on GitHub.
See https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-applications/

The documentation is quite overwhelming, and you need to familiarize yourself with a bunch of concepts too. As a starter, you need to grasp following concepts:

- **Project structure** 
  Gradle uses the default folder structure introduced by Maven: 
  `src/main/java` for Java sources 
  `src/main/resources` for resources (get bundled into the JAR/WAR/EAR)
  `src/test/java` for Java test sources 
  `src/test/resources` for test resources
- **Build file** 
  The `build.gradle` file defines your project and how it should be built. Each project/artefact has a **groupId**, **artefactId** and **version**.
- **Build tasks** 
  Gradle projects use plugins (such as the 'java' plugin for building Java projects). Learn about the build tasks (`clear`, `test`, `build`, `deploy`, execute `gradle tasks` to list all tasks.
- **Dependencies** 
  External libraries you use shouldn't be downloaded and put into the project `lib` folder, but rather you *declare* dependencies to libraries (browse for them on [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/). Gradle will take care of the dependency management and download libs and transient dependencies automatically.
- **External resource loading** 
  You project contains a file-DB. Is it read-only? Bundle it as resource and load it over the class loader, not a file. Is it writeable? Keep it outside the project, and access it over a URL or file path. Consider to make the URL/path configurable (command line args).

Here's the generic `build.gradle` which I use as a starter for my projects (with a cleaner approach to managing dependencies), for JDK 9/10/11+ you can change the compatibility java version to 9/10/11+:

```
defaultTasks 'clean', 'build'
apply plugin: 'java'

description = 'Example Java Project'
group = 'org.test'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

ext.libs = [
        testbase: [
                "junit:junit:4.12"
        ],
        loggingAPI   : [
                "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25"
        ],
        loggingImpl  : [
                "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.25",
                "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25",
                "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
        ]
]

dependencies {
    testCompile libs.testbase
    compile libs.loggingAPI
    compile libs.loggingImpl
}
```

Comment: Thx! But is it exactly the same for JavaFx project as well? I didn't try those tutorials because I don't wish the subtle differences in configuration (if any) trip me up at the end.

Comment: When using Gradle, there is [a plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin) for everything.

Comment: Since JDK9 the source and target compatibility should be specified as 9, 10, 11, 12. There is no version 1.9 for example.